# Bash script to retrieve files from Azure blob with nested structure

Tags: bash, azure, azure-blob-storage

I'm definitely not an expert with Bash scripting but I need to compose one that retrieves  multiple files from an Azure blob and saves them to a local directory.

The files in Azure are saved into nested folders with this schema: {Namespace}/{EventHub}/{PartitionId}/{Year}/{Month}/{Day}/{Hour}/{Minute}/{Second}

Any suggestions on the syntax that I'd need to use to fetch these files?

Thanks in advance!